# Mysql avoid redundant foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have the following database schema:
[image: Picture of the model]

`t_class`: Stores metadata about a class (primary key: `class_ID`)

`t_students`: linked to class by foreign key `class_ID`

`t_exams`: Stores metadata about an exam (no foreign keys so far)

`t_grades`: Links `t_exams` to `t_students` as the both having a n to m relationsship (has no primary key, but two foreign keys: `exam_ID` and `student_ID`). It also has the column `grade` which stores the result of each student in an exam.

**The problem**: It is possible that `t_grades` has no entries for a particular exam. With the current schema there's no way to get all exams of a **class** if `t_grades` has no entry.

**My solution**:
a) Add a key `class_ID` to `t_exams`. Downsides: It is more a less a redundant key and I can't add it as a foreign key (results in mysql error 1452)
b) Automatically add all students of a class to `t_grades` and just leave `t_grades.grade` empty. This feels very redundant as well.

**Question:** Is there a better way to solve this specific problem or should I stick with one of my solutions?

**Create Code:**

- [Sample database from this post](http://pastebin.com/xaRvQs1e)
- [From the actual database I'm using (it's mostly German unfortunately](https://github.com/l3d00m/grade_manager/blob/4739b42a861f908ea977890d63d279dd6445ae42/db.sql)

Comment: You are not diagramming correctly. What modeling/diagramming reference do you think you're using? (You're also misusing "metadata".) (You also don't understand primary keys.) PS Please do not use links, cut and paste relevant text into your question.

Comment: @philipxy I modelled the diagram using a software called "Xerdi" (used by my prof).  As far as I understood this database is pretty good in terms of normalisation. What exactly is wrong about my primary keys and metadata? I wrote this completely by myself, as you can see in my github project (https://github.com/l3d00m/grade_manager/ ). I did not copy paste anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't like the way you've graphed your database design, but I understand your problem.

In my opinion you should connect the `t_exams` directly to `t_classes`, since all students in a class should take the exam. So, that's your first solution.

In simple terms: A student belongs to a class, a class can get an exam, and an exam, a student took, can be graded.
[image]

This seems like a perfectly logical design to me. I don't get why you cannot implement this? I guess we need to see your `CREATE TABLE` queries?

I agree: My graph is also far from perfect, but just like with yours: I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Your graphics explains it a lot better! I've recreated the db the way I described it and added the create code to the question. However, it now works like a charm in this database. It seems like it's an unrelated problem with my original database and had not so much to do with the fact that it was redundant. I've also added the code to the original database (but it's mostly in German :( ). I'll hopefully figure it out. Sorry for the troubles and thanks a lot for your help anyway!

Comment: Ah, nice, I was expecting the error was somewhat unrelated.